# What is a Madoni

Tags: words, maseches-kiddushin

[Kiddushin 26b:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.26b.3?lang=bi&with=Notes&lang2=en) mentions this term - what type of person is this?

ת"ש אמר ר' אלעזר מעשה במדוני אחד שהיה בירושלים שהיו לו מטלטלין הרבה וביקש ליתנם במתנה אמרו לו אין לו תקנה עד שיקנם על גבי קרקע מה עשה הלך ולקח בית סלע סמוך לירושלים ואמר צפוני זה לפלוני ועמו מאה צאן ומאה חביות ומת וקיימו את דבריו

Come and hear, as Rabbi Elazar said: There was an incident involving a certain Madonite [Madoni] who was in Jerusalem, as he had a great deal of movable property and wished to give it as a gift. He was ill and did not have time for the recipient to acquire the property by pulling. The Sages said to him: One in this situation has no remedy but to transfer them by means of land. What did he do? He went and acquired a beit sela, apparently meaning land the size of a sela coin, near Jerusalem and said: This northern portion of the beit sela is given to so-and-so, and with it one hundred sheep and one hundred barrels. And the Madonite died, and the Sages fulfilled his statement and gave the gifts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The footnotes in the [Soncino Talmud](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nashim/Kiddushin.pdf) write concerning the מדוני:

> A townsman of Meron in Galilee, south of Giscala. The reading here and in the MS. F of B.B. 156b is מדוני .

Similarly, if you look in [Jastrow's dictionary](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/) under מדוני, he leads you to the word מרוני, which he says there:

[image]

So a "Madonite" is someone from the town of [Meron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meron,_Israel).